# Why utf-8 character does not show in cmd.exe?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, utf-8, cmd

I am testing c++11 string literal with tdm-gcc under windows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << u8"你确定要这么做吗" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

command line:

```
e:\src\c++\11>g++ utf8_literal.cc -std=c++11
```

change the code to utf8 with `chcp 65001` then run the application, turns out to be
[image: the first character does not show]

The first Chinese character `你` is incorrect. But if add a English character e.g. `a` then the display is correct:
[image: the correct image precede with a]

Thus we could rule out the font problem. Why the first character refuse to show without an English character preceding it?

Comment: I'd look for something like "stream orientation" maybe.

Comment: The reason is the the cmd.exe console does not properly support utf-8. There is no fixing it, unless you work for Microsoft.

Comment: I wondered if it might be BOM-related. I just did a few experiments but nothing conclusive. You should definitely follow the above advice to redirect output to a hex editor, and confirm exactly which byte sequence is being output. (And repeat with the "a" prefix.)

Comment: I don't know about the g++ implementation of the standard library, but at least with Microsoft's, `std::cout` doesn't properly write UTF-8 encoded text to the console. You will either need to convert it to UTF-16 (e.g. using `MultiByteToWideChar`), or output the text using the `WriteConsoleA` function.

Answer (score 0):

The string after std::cout: `u8"你确定要这么做吗"` is not in UTF-8 encoding.

For UTF-8 encoding, please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

The UTF-8 code for the string is:

```
E4 BD A0 E7 A1 AE E5 AE 9A E8 A6 81 E8 BF 99 E4 B9 88 E5 81 9A E5 90 97
```